# RSpec 2 testing uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I know I should be testing validations, but I'm learning so would like to know why my code doesn't work.

Environment Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1, RSpect 2.6.4

I got a Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title, :description, :image_url, :price

  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :image_url, :message => "can't be blank"
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :message => "must be unique"
  validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01, :message => "must be a number greater than 0"
  validates_format_of :image_url, :with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i, :message => "is a invalid image file"
end
```

in the spec/models/product_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Product do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { 
      :title => "Lorem Ipsum",
      :description => "Wibbling is fun!",
      :image_url => "lorem.jpg",
      :price => 19.99
    }
  end

  it "rejects duplicated titles" do
    Product.create!(@attr)
    product_with_duplicate_title = Product.new(@attr)
    product_with_duplicate_title.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

When I run rack rspec, I got:

```
Failures:

  1) Product should reject if the title is duplicated
     Failure/Error: product_with_duplicate_title.should_not be_valid
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Why? I also tried something similar using factory_girl, and got the same result… other tests (not included here) for testing blanks, valid image file names, etc., all worked.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You'd better follow a far easier path: using shoulda matchers along with Rspec. You'd end up simply writing:

```
describe Product do
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:title) }
end
```

[Doc here](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames).

Comment: I'd also suggest using some kind of factory to generate the values, see http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=✓&query=factory. I use Fabricator but there are plenty (Factory Girl is the widest used, I think)

Comment: Though by using another extra gem shoulda can help solve the problem, it still does not help me understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you still.

Comment: Lain. Thanx. I did try the same thing with Factory_girl and got the same error.

Comment: i suspect `be_valid` since it's no more in documentation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers  Did you try `product_with_duplicate_title.valid?.should be_false`

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks valid, I don't understand why it isn't working. I noticed you are still using the old Rails 2.x syntax which was deprecated in Rails 3. That shouldn't be the problem, I think the syntax is still supported in Rails 3.1.

Here is how I would write something similar:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Using FactoryGirl as Iain mentions above.

```
let(:product) { FactoryGirl.build(:product) }    

it "has a unique title" do
  older_product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
  product.title = older_product.title
  product.should_not be_valid
end
```

Can you try to print out the errors? Maybe it isn't failing on the title uniqueness but on some other field?

Comment: I might suggest `create!` instead of `create`. I had a case where my "duplicate" wasn't actually saving due to a validation error, so it looked like my uniqueness validation was broken even though it wasn't.